# Can't pin files to taskbar after downgrade to Win7

Tags: windows-7, start-menu, downgrade

This has happened to three computers so far:

- Upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10
- Downgraded back down to Windows 7
- Files that were previously pinned to app in taskbar have disappeared
- Dragging files to taskbar icon does not work; they do not show up when you right click icon in taskbar.

Any thoughts? Google-fu fails :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my own problem. Technically these pinned shortcuts are called "jump lists". The solution was to delete the existing jump lists:

http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/clear-recent-items-windows-jumplists/

In summary:

1. Open file explorer and go to the following folders via typing or copy/paste (they are hidden system folders and can't be browsed to):

   1. %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations
   2. %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations
2. Move or delete all the items so these folders are empty.
3. Pin a file to the task bar. It should now work.

Alternately, if you are trying to avoid re-pinning all your files, you could start by deleting the largest files in these hidden system folders. This thread suggests that some of the largest files may be the cause of this issue:

http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/22202-problem-jump-list-fails-work.html